# Rails CSS3 Vote Bar

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, youtube, vote

I have using Acts_as_votable and I want to display a youtube-like dislike-like bar. 
I have looked around and cant seem to find something that will have two separate colours (green & red) from each side and if there is 1 Like and 0 Dislikes, fill the bar with 100 % green and vice versa. 
So if there are, say, 80 Likes and 20 Dislikes, fill the bar with 80% Green and 20% Red

This is the code for

- all votes `<%= @movie.votes.size %>`
- like votes `<%= @movie.upvotes.size %>`
- dislike votes `<%= @movie.downvotes.size %>`

So could you please help me with either a link or a JSFiddle/Codepen with a css progress bar that could work with my rails.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way is http://jsfiddle.net/achr3f/FtsXp/

To get this feature with rails you can do something like that

```
.vote
  .up-vote{style: "width: #{@movies.upvotes}%"}
  .down-vote{style: "width: #{@movies.downvotes}%"}
```

css

```
.vote{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 9px;
}

.up-vote{
  float: left;
  height: 9px;
  background: green;
}

.down-vote{
  float: left;
  height: 9px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: But then if there is 1 like and 0 dislikes, it still becomes 1% and 0%
Which means that only 1% of the bar would be green. 
What i want is the whole bar to be green if there is still 1 like and 0 dislikes

Comment: @PMP it's  easy to get the average from count of likes, for example
when you have only one like, 
(count)like / count(votes) * 100 = 100 (%), so never-mind the number of likes  (%) like + (%) dislikes = 100 % 

:)